# Displaying the same and only one content of the menu items of two identical menus in React when clicking on them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with 2 identical menus in React, one is located in the header tag and second in footer tag. I have done the routing, but I want now that the content of the same menu items in both menus is only once displayed, and that this is visible when clicking. The content should be located in  tags. How can I do this? I tried like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, NavLink, Redirect, Prompt} from 'react-router-dom';
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import About from '../About/About';
import Work from '../Work/Work';
import Contact from '../Contact/Contact';

const main = () => {
    return (
       <Router>
            <div>
                <ul className="navigation">
                    <NavLink className="home" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="about" to="/about">About</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="work" to="/work">Work</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="contact" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
                </ul>

                <Route className="Home" path="/" exact strict component={Home}/>
                <Route className="About" path="/about" exact strict component={About}/>
                <Route className="Work" path="/work" exact strict component={Work}/>
                <Route className="Contact" path="/contact" exact strict component={Contact}/>

                <ul className="navigation">
                    <NavLink className="home" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="about" to="/about">About</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="work" to="/work">Work</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="contact" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default main;
```

But in this case everything should be in one component, because one should be located in header, and the other in the footer, any idea?

Found solution:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App">
                    <header>    
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="container">
                                <Header />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Menu /> 
                    </header>
                    <main>    
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="container">
                                <Menu /> 
                                <Route className="Home" path="/" exact strict component={Home}/>
                                <Route className="About" path="/about" exact strict component={About}/>
                                <Route className="Work" path="/work" exact strict component={Work}/>
                                <Route className="Contact" path="/contact" exact strict component={Contact}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <footer>
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="container">
                            <Menu /> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and I separated Menu as  component in a separate file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, NavLink, Redirect, Prompt} from 'react-router-dom';
const menu = () => {
    return (
        <ul className="navigation">
            <NavLink className="home" to="/">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="about" to="/about">About</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="work" to="/work">Work</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="contact" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
        </ul>
    )
}

export default menu;
```

Components are amazing.

Comment: Hello. Can you please share some of the code you've written so we can try to help out? Thanks

Comment: Hi, please edit your original question with the code you've tried - will be much simpler to read than in the comments, thanks!